# How to SSH into apache web server

Tags: apache, ssh, putty, web-development-server

I am new to web development.
I have set up a Apache 2.4 web server windows and would like to create a web application. I would like to upload files (JavaScript, style sheets ..etc) onto the server. I have been googling for hours and can not figure out how to ssh onto the server. The server is barebones, I can put the IP address into a browser on other computers and access the index.html. What are my next steps so I can ssh onto the server and view my web application?

Answer (score 0):

Apache makes your machine a *web server* so that you can connect to it using the HTTP and HTTPS protocols. Data for these are typically exchanged on the TCP ports 80 and 443. (Ports are basically positive numbers up to 65535 exchanged within data packets to identify the intended use by the target machine of a packet over the network.)

To be able to log into a machine using ssh you need to set up an *ssh server* on that machine. For example you might choose OpenSSH. The SSH traffic will typically use TCP port 22. It is independent of whether your Apache web server is running or not.

You will also have to install an ssh client (e.g. putty and scp) on the machine(s) which should connect to the server to upload the scripts and files.

To reduce risks of unwanted connections from the Internet, choose a strong password or switch to certificate-based authentication. Additionally, you might want to configure the firewalls so that the server will accept SSH connections only from the network where your ssh client machine is expected to communicate from. (Since HTTP and HTTPS use different ports, the web server could still be accessed from the wide Internet.)

Then you could compare your machine with web and ssh services to a house with a telephone connection and a doorbell. Probably many people should in principle be able to phone you. But you will want that only those who are physically nearby can ring the door bell and potentially enter.